# Expectation of X choose k

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, expected-value

Let $X$ be a random variable, assume that we know $\mathbb{E}\left[ X \choose k \right] $.
Can I assume
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[ X \choose k \right] =  {\mathbb{E}\left[  X \right]\choose k}$$ as k is not a random variable?

Comment: What is the distribution of $X$? For general $X$ this notion of $X \choose k$ is problematic.

Comment: Test it out when $X \sim unif\{-1,1\}$ and $k=2$. Note here $EX=0$...

Comment: Well, $\binom Xk=\frac1{k!}X(X-1)\cdots(X-k+1)$, therefore essentially you can't expect the identity to hold more than you can expect $E[X^m]=(E[X])^m$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not true. If, for instance $X \sim \text{Binomial}(n,p)$ with $n = 10$ and $p=0.55$ then $\mathbb E[X] = 5.5$ and ${\mathbb{E}\left[  X \right]\choose k}$ is not defined.

Applying the [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician), we have that
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[ X \choose k \right] = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} {i \choose k}\mathbb P(X=i) $$
And there is no reason for that sum to be equal to ${\mathbb{E}\left[  X \right]\choose k}$ in general.

Answer (score 6):

If you want this to hold for all $k$, then the answer is **NO**, even if $X$ takes value in integers, unless $X$ is constant. For example we take $k=2$, what you suggest will be $\mathbb{E}\frac{X(X-1)}{2}=\frac{(\mathbb{E}X)(\mathbb{E}X-1)}{2}$, which is equivalent to

$$\mathbb{E}X^2-\mathbb{E}X=(\mathbb{E}X)^2-\mathbb{E}X\Longleftrightarrow \mathbb{E}X^2=(\mathbb{E}X)^2\Longleftrightarrow Var(X)=0,$$

thus $X$ should be constant.